# css or javascript for animation

Tags: javascript, css

I am confused, I read that `css` animation is not supported by some browsers; so, between `css` and `javascript`, which is the better one to use for animation?

Please suggest or present some advantages/disadvantages for the two choices.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at CSS3 based animations we have basically two different kinds of animation. One is KeyFrame-Based while the other one is Transition-Based. These animations are completly relying on the Browser implementation of animating the elements, where JS based animations are implementing them by themselves. A big advantage of CSS animations is that they will perform better because they use the browsers routine and that they will even work in a "NoScript-Envoirement".

---

**CSS Transition**

A CSS Transition is basically when you change some CSS properties.
For example, when you hover over this rectangle, it gets bigger and the `transition`-Property in CSS makes it a smooth animation.

```css
#rectangle{
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: width 1s linear; // The transition property sets how the transition-animation behaves
}

#rectangle:hover{
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">test</div>
```

[Read more about css transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

---

**CSS KeyFrames**

While transitions mostly are being used to get changings of elements in a nice animation way, there is also a KeyFrame-Based approach of using CSS to create "scripted" animations for like an character or something. This is a little more complex, because you need to specify your exact animations using `@keyframes` and then setting the animation settings with the `<animation>`-Property and its sub-properties. Also, the KeyFrame animation isnt being called when a value changes, its more like you can decide when to show it and how to loop though it.

```css
/* example from http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color: red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color: yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color: blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color: green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color: red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

#rectangle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">test</div>
```

[Read more about css keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

---

**JS Animations**

JS Animations are other than CSS animations. They mostly have an own implementation to display the animation. Therefor the performace on JS animations will be worse than when using CSS animation. One big advantage (and in my opinion the only time you should use JS-Animations over CSS-Animations) is the fact that you have a scripting language behind it and you can basically create anything you want. I recommend you looking though some libraries or existing sources since creating your own JS based animations may end up working very slow. There are multiple libs which provide you with more or less animation techniques:

- [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)
- [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/)
- [DynamicJS](http://dynamicsjs.com/)

---

As I said, in my opinion today you can mostly rely on CSS animations and using JS only in cases where you need a scripting language to do your wanted animation.